Android Studio ndkCamera landscape preview rotate 90(270) degree
The view that i opened camera originally work perfect,after i set this activity to android:screenOrientation="landscape",the preview rotate 90(270)degree. I am using ndkCamera.cpp/ndkCamera.h from here.
My main goal is to keep camera being landscape.Also let preview show correctly. PLEASE someone can help me!

can you specify you are capturing from front-facing and back-facing camera ?

I am capture from back-facing

As the camera pointing to the back and you are using landscape mode, it must be rotated at an angle of zero-degree to be projected on a screen. Does u have any function like ndkcamera_setDisplayOrientation(0) ?
